# Trying to create Cortana search equivalent

Tags: search, ubuntu-mate

One of my most missed features in Windows 10 is Cortana, which kicks Siri's butt IMHO:)
Anyone know of a way to duplicate Cortana somewhow in Ubuntu(mate in my case)?

I'm not interested in speech or image recognition, something like Sirius is way too much for my needs. Just a powerful search utility I can access from my panel
http://www.pcworld.com/article/2898148/meet-sirius-the-open-source-siri-clone-that-runs-on-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have connected this script to a keyboard shortcut for when I am holding my five month old son. It is quicker than having to type with one hand. I have an SSD so launching Chromium is fast. If you have an HDD, you'll need to use `pgrep` to see if Chromium is running already, if so, sleep less time, if not sleep more time until Chromium loads. (I could add this segment if needed.) The sleep aspect is there so all page content loads before running the `xdotool` command at the end. I am assuming here that you would be using Chromium and that your default page is the Google search page. My script also moves Chromium to the middle monitor, but I have commented out those lines assuming you have one screen. You will need `xdotool` installed with the command `sudo apt install xdotool` for the script to work. The following is less instant than other virtual assistants, but it works every time for me. It basically selects the little Google Now/Search microphone and hits enter for you.

```
#!/bin/bash

chromium-browser &

sleep 3

# window_id=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
# Un-maximize to move
# wmctrl -ir $window_id -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
# Move window to middle screen
# xdotool windowmove $window_id 2000 200
# Maximize again
# wmctrl -ir $window_id -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
# sleep 1

# I need to do 6 tabs then enter.
xdotool key Tab Tab Tab Tab Tab Tab Return
```

Comment: @eco_bach Please let me know if you needed any help setting up the panel launcher.

Comment: Nice shortcut. Thanks for sharing. However when I try and run it I get chromium-browser: command not found
Google Chrome is however installed.

Comment: @eco_bach In the script, you would replace `chromium-browser` with `google-chrome-stable`.